# How to retrieve files if removed with git rm without any prior commit?

Tags: git

Accidentally ran `git rm -r` and lost all files.
Had no prior commits.
Tried using `git reset`

Comment: Reset works on the index. Unless the files were tracked by git (i.e., they were present in some commit, even if only on the local repo on your machine) I don't think there's any way to recover it. Exceptionally, if it was a Java project and you use IntelliJ, you can recover it from local history.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds Horrible!
But luckily there is a way.
Create bash script `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run git fsck to check objects and store the results in a variable
fsck_result=$(git fsck --full 2>&1)

# Create a file to store the git show output
touch git_show_output.txt
output_file="git_show_output.txt"

# Loop through the objects found by git fsck
echo "$fsck_result" | grep "dangling blob" | cut -d' ' -f3 | while read commit
do
    echo "Object: $commit"
    git show $commit >> $output_file
done

# Display the git show output
cat $output_file
```

make it executable using `chmod +x script.sh`

and execute it `./script.sh`

You can now search through the content of `git_show_output.txt` and find your files there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where this script comes from? Doesn’t look that it is yours.

Comment: Found the fsck command here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-in-git/

Comment: Then asked chatgpt to concat each blob to file

Comment: this is very low quality.  your concatenation is flat out broken.. you just put all the contents of the commits one after the other, without even a line separator potentially with the same file multiple times with no file labels.    ChatGPT is banned for a reason. And if he didnt commit or stage anything there wont be anything to recover

Comment: OP says the files were removed by `git rm` and not `git reset`. I fail to understand how/why you think it's possible to recover file that was never tracked by Git in the first place. In the tutorial that you liked, in the section *How to Restore Changes that Are Neither Committed nor Staged* it clearly states that **In the case where the changes are neither staged nor committed, Git can't help you recover the files.**

Comment: You are right. The files were staged but before committing it was removed.